# Can you confirm the term 'Save' in NHibernate terminology stands for INSERT?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate, insert

I am a beginner to NHibbernate and currently I am trying to understand 'cascade' attribute and its setting options.

If you are familier with Nhibernate you already know one of the setting options for cascade attribute is: "save-update"

And it is explained (in [www.ayende.com](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update) site) as: "when the object is saved/updated, check the assoications and save/update any object that require it (including save/update the assoications in many-to-many scenario)."

***Can yo confirm in Nhibernate terminology SAVE stands for INSERT in SQL?
And do you know if there is any reason for using SAVE term instaed of INSERT?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NHibernate's `Save-Update` applies to both `UPDATE` and `INSERT` SQL statements.

Cascade options relate to what NHibernate should do about other related entities when saving an entity. As [Ayende writes in that post](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update)

- **None** - do not do any cascades, let the users handles them by themselves.
- **Save-Update** - when the object is saved/updated, check the associations and save/update any object that require it (including save/update the associations in many-to-many scenario).
- **Delete** - when the object is deleted, delete all the objects in the association.
- **Delete-Orphan** - when the object is deleted, delete all the objects in the association. In addition to that, when an object is removed from the association and not associated with another object (orphaned), also delete it.
- **All** - when an object is save/update/delete, check the associations and save/update/delete all the objects found.
- **All-Delete-Orphan** - when an object is save/update/delete, check the associations and save/update/delete all the objects found. In additional to that, when an object is removed from the association and not associated with another object (orphaned), also delete it.

So, **Save-Update** basically says to NHibernate, "when saving my entity, if any objects associated with the entity are transient (not yet persisted), then persist (save) them." Any associated objects that are already persistent will be updated.

The reason why it's called `Save-Update` is maybe that it applies to [`Save()`, `Update()` and `SaveOrUpdate()`](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata)

In [Fabio Maulo's NHibernate documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-2-architecture#Chapter%28C2%29%28A0%292%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Architecture), [Chapter 9.9 talks about LifeStyles and Object graphs](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-9-manipulating-persistent-data#9%282E%299%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Lifecyles_and_object_graphs):

> NHibernate does not fully implement "persistence by reachability",
>   which would imply (inefficient) persistent garbage collection.
>   However, due to popular demand, NHibernate does support the notion of
>   entities becoming persistent when referenced by another persistent
>   object. Associations marked cascade="save-update" behave in this way.
>   If you wish to use this approach throughout your application, it's
>   easier to specify the default-cascade attribute of the
>    element.

Comment: But then why they call it 'save-update' instead of only 'save' ?

Comment: Sure ... `UPDATE` if your entity has PK and, otherwise, `INSERT`.

Comment: **THIS ANSWER IS INCORRECT. SAVE-UPDATE CASCADING HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH DIRTY TRACKING**

Comment: @Diego - no need to shout :) Maybe `dirty` is the wrong choice of word as this means something different in an NHibernate context. How would you describe its behaviour? NHibernate will make associated objects persistent when referenced by a persistent object when using `Save-Update` and persistent associated objects will be updated, correct?

Comment: @RussCam: dirty entities will be updated regardless of any cascading settings. See my addition to Jamie's answer. Sorry about the caps; it was just my reaction to seeing an incorrect answer being upvoted and accepted without criticism.

Answer (score 2):

Save is not equivalent to insert, although in most applications calling Save results in one or more inserts.

Save makes a transient object persistent. Update makes a detached object persistent. [Understanding these concepts](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-9-manipulating-persistent-data#) are the key to using NHibernate effectively.

`cascade="save-update"` means that referenced entities that are not yet persistent will also be saved when saving or updating that entity.

Without that attribute, NHibernate will tell you the referenced entity is transient when trying to flush (unless you save it manually)

Comment: But you can even update a persistence object if you are in the same session's scope. UPDATe should not be limited to detached objects only. Don't you think so?

Comment: If you're in the same session's scope then Update is not needed, the changes will be persisted when the session is flushed. Unfortunately the NHibernate Update method shares a name with the SQL statement and that's the source of much confusion. The linked documentation explains this.